# How to prevent lag in java game

Tags: java, swing

I'm designing Snakes and Ladders game. I'm using a timer to loop through the images of the dice and also for the ladders, snakes classes.

I'm having trouble when I'm using `Thread.sleep()` to have some latency between the pc turn and the player turn. The problem is that there's a lag in the middle of any process for the timer e.g when the player button is placed on any square that has a ladder, the button is taking time till it's getting to the top of the ladder. And same with the snakes and the dice.

I've looked up in Google a lot but I couldn't find any solution. Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: The only answer I can give with this information is the general answer.  Don't do any processing on the Swing event thread.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that `Thread.sleep()` sounds suspiciously like 'block the EDT'.

Comment: Sorry for any incomplete information but The only reason why I didn't post any code is that my code is more than 500 lines. @ Gilbert Le Blanc, if the button is placed on any square that has a ladders, it has to move up till it gets to the top of the ladders, and that's where the lag is starting. Is there any other way I can use to make a delay between pc turn and player turn instead of Thread. sleep() ? Thanks.. @ Anish Gupta, Sorry about that but I'm new to this website, I'll definitely do :)

Comment: Note that nobody so far has suggested you post your 'code'.  I suggested an SSCCE, which is not the same thing.  Follow (read) the link for details.

Comment: Try looking at this article, and if you're up to it, studying the source code of LWJGL.  http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_4_%28Timing%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a timestamp at the start and the end of the work to determine how long the work took to perform and then subtract that from your sleep time.

Alternatively use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) if you want something to execute at a fixed interval.

Comment: *"Get a time.."* ..machine we're headed back to 1.4!  Please don't link to the JavaDocs for an obsolete JRE.